# How to map/reduce a list into an alist?

Tags: mapping, alists

Given a `list` of things, I want to create an `alist` by applying a function which creates elements of the `alist`.

For example, what is the implementation of `doit` here:

```lisp
(doit '("a" "b" "c"))
;; => (("a" . "A") ("b" . "B") ("c" . "C"))
```

Comment: You should be more specific in your questions. The answer you accepted does not exactly answer your question. Mine, yes.

Comment: Thank you for feedback @gigiair. But My question is how to to create an alist. The example with the `doit` function was just an example to make my question more clear. The answer from @jagrg is just perfect. It captures the essence of the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapcar` is another option:

```lisp
(mapcar (lambda (x)
          (cons x (upcase x)))
        '("a" "b" "c"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be

```
(defun doit (l)
  (seq-map (lambda (x)
             (cons x (upcase x))) l))
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using `seq-map` over `mapcar`? ( `seq-map` defined in `seq.el.gz` seems to be only a wrapper to `mapcar`)

Comment: seq-map operates on sequences of any type.. It is not just a wrapper.

Comment: @Claudio: deleted